# jQuery functions are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I modified the menu animation code from this page ...

https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/Atyop

... and have the button open and close my menu (on click, it should show and hide #mainmenu ... by toggling the class .menuview on and off). However, it's not working. Not sure what happened ... and need some help. I've been racking my brain over this for awhile...

My code is below...

**JAVASCRIPT**. I don't see anything wrong...

```
// Menu Button        
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-icon3').click(function(){
        $('#mainmenu').toggleClass('menuview');
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

**HTML** (I'm using WordPress to show the menu)

```
<div id="mainmenu">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-navigation', 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="menu" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>' ) ); ?>
</div>   

<div id="nav-icon3">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

**STYLES** (this is the responsive section of the stylesheet. Full stylesheet at http://www.silkvodka.com/wp-content/themes/silkvodka/style.css )

```
    #mainmenu { position: absolute; top: -59999px; left: -59999px; /* Hide Menu */}
#mainmenu.menuview { position:absolute; top:60px; left:10px; display:block; float:none; width:146px; z-index:99; }

#nav-icon3 { display:block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  float:none;
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:200px;
  background-color:#494949;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon3 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 40px;
  margin:0 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 1px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) { top: 17px; }
#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2), 
#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) { top: 30px; }
#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) { top: 43px; }

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) { top: 14px; width: 0%; left: 50%;}
#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) { 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) { top: 14px; width: 0%; left: 50%; }
```

You can view the entire page here: http://www.silkvodka.com/cocktails/ (use a small browser window, otherwise, the responsive button wont be visible)

Comment: You should tag this with 'jquery', since it's clearly a question about a jquery feature.

Comment: Seems like your not loading jquery at all.  I went to the site and there was a console error on the page.

Comment: Yes, the page was loading jquery. See the actual site and view source (referenced above). However, problem resolved, so no more responses necessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are loading your javascript.js file before jquery. Your javascript.js file attempts to use jquery... switch these script tags around like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.silkvodka.com/wp-content/themes/silkvodka/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.silkvodka.com/wp-content/themes/silkvodka/js/javascript.js"></script>
```

This was evident by the console error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" which indicates you are attempting to use jquery berfore it's available.

Comment: I think his problems are combination of both of our answers. Yours most specifically right off the bat. I am curious as to see if he fixes the script ordering if there is still a problem. I think there might be. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

When using wordpress, use jQuery instead of $

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#nav-icon3').click(function(){
        jQuery('#mainmenu').toggleClass('menuview');
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

That should run :)

Comment: Also, if it is still not working, put that code in your console and try execute it. If it works in your console, then your problem will be that your code is being loaded too soon in the page. You can use this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/

Add the js, and you can select to insert the js in the footer rather that the header. Also select external file.

Comment: Didn't matter if it was javascript or jQuery... it just mattered if I loaded the javascript.js file AFTER The jquery.min.js file.